# printf the last Byte of a hex value in C

Tags: c

I have a simple question.
The code is really short so I just post it here

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    long int p;

    printf("FYI: address of first local varaible of main() on the function stack:%p\n",&p);
    printf("Enter start address <hex notation> of dump:");
    scanf("%lx",&p);

    char * q;
    q = (char*)p;

    printf("%x\n",*q);

    return 0;
}
```

The result of last printf, for example is ffffffc8. What if I only want to keep the last two: c8. How can I do that? I tried:
 `printf("%2x",*q);`
and
 `printf("%x",*q % 256);` 
But neither works. Can some one help? Thanks!

Comment: There may be a more root-cause answer over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463962/printf-char-as-hex-in-c/30464318#30464318 -- specifically, you need to cast the value as an unsigned int or add the 'hh' specifier to limit the size to char (per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To print the least-significant byte of `*q` in hex you could use:

```
printf("%02x", *q & 0xFF);
```

This of course assumes that `q` can be dereferenced.

Comment: Thank you that works. But I want to use a for loop to this printf for more than one address. like printf("%2x",*(q++) & 0xFF); Sometimes the  in the memory it is empty, the result is 0. Is there a way to make it also 00. So I can make the print result very tidy.(Two number in every result).

Comment: @lancellx: The code in my current answer already does that (the format is `"%02x"` -- note the `0`).

Answer (score 0):

First convert to unsigned:

```
unsigned char q = *(unsigned char *)(p);
printf("%02X", q);
```

(Otherwise, if your `char` is signed, the variadic default promotion converts the value to `int`, and the result may be negative.)

Comment: I did't try you answer because I have to use pointer.(School assignment..) Thank you all the same.

Comment: @User1: Hm, I see. A matter of debate, I suppose, whether the OP means the "last two" character of the binary representation of the integer, or the remainder modulo 256 of the integer.  She should just read into a `uintptr_t` and print `p % 0x100` in that case, I suppose.