# printf char as hex in c

Tags: c, printf

I expect ouput something like `\9b\d9\c0...` from code below, but I'm getting `\ffffff9b\ffffffd9\ffffffc0\ffffff9d\53\ffffffa9\fffffff4\49\ffffffb0\ffff
ffef\ffffffd9\ffffffaa\61\fffffff7\54\fffffffb`. I added explicit casting to char, but it has no effect. What's going on here?

```c
typdef struct PT {
    // ... omitted
    char GUID[16];
} PT;
PT *pt;
// ... omitted
int i;
for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
    printf("\\%02x", (char) pt->GUID[i]);
}
```

**Edit:** only casting to `(unsigned char)` worked for me. Compiler spits warnings on me when using `%02hhx` (`gcc -Wall`). `(unsigned int)` had no effect.

Comment: is it not like that `%x` considers `unsigned int` as argument?

Comment: The number `2` in `%02` always specifies the minimum number of digits in the field. `printf` will use the smallest implemented type, an `unsigned int` to print the value. This is the reason for the result.

Comment: Why would you *add* an explicit cast to `char` (which you already have)? I would think `(unsigned int)` would be more what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf the last Byte of a hex value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296032/printf-the-last-byte-of-a-hex-value-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that `char`s on your system are signed. When you pass them to functions with variable number of arguments, such as `printf` (outside of fixed-argument portion of the signature) `char`s get converted to `int`, and they get sign-extended in the process.

To fix this, cast the value to `unsigned char`:

```
printf("\\%02hhx", (unsigned char) pt->GUID[i]);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RhzgHB)

Comment: Also change the conversion specifier to `%02hhx`.

Comment: `X` to make the hex in uppercase, if someone needed it.

Comment: this is also relevant to the problem [https://github.com/LambdaSchool/CS-Wiki/wiki/Casting-Signed-to-Unsigned-in-C](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/CS-Wiki/wiki/Casting-Signed-to-Unsigned-in-C)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
printf("\%02hhx", pt->GUID[i]);
```

Because `printf()` is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments), its arguments are [promoted to `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integer_promotion). The `hh` modifier tells [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) that the type of the corresponding value is `unsigned char` and not `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to `unsigned char` instead, to avoid a leading 1 bit being interpreted as a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you were getting the F's when the number was larger than 99x.

I wrote this to test it out and discovered the hh prefix at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```
#include "stdio.h"

char GUID[16];

int main() {
int i;
for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
    GUID[i]=i*i;
}
for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
    printf("\\%02.2hhx\n", GUID[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a small own implementation to solve this problem on all platforms:

```
char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";

void printHex(unsigned char byte) {
    printf("%c%c", hex[byte>>4], hex[byte&0xf]);
}
```