# Trouble converting device token Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to convert a device token and using the following code (swift 3):

```
parameters["device_token"] = request.deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)}).
```

However I am getting the compiler error `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type Any? and String`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

var token = ""

for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
 token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
  }

  print("Registration succeeded!")
  print("Token: ", token)
 }
```

Comment: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'`. Getting that error.

Comment: Brilliant that worked. Can you tell me what `format: "%02.2hhx"` does?

Comment: @KexAri - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463962/printf-char-as-hex-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code using `reduce` to convert the device token to
a hex string is correct. But apparently `parameters` has the type
`NSMutableDictionary` (or `[String: Any]`), and the compiler tries to
match the initial value `""` to `Any?`.

As a workaround, you can assign the hex string to a temporary variable
first:

```
let hexToken = request.deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
parameters["device_token"] = hexToken
```

or use the trailing closure syntax instead:

```
parameters["device_token"] = deviceToken.reduce("") {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)}
```

Both methods make your code compile, so this could be a compiler bug.